# Could HTML file be reused dynamically?

Tags: javascript

If a website needs to have a page for every item, is it better to manually create pages with the same HTML code but different titles/images/descriptions or create only one but add content through javascrpit depending on a page a user followed, like that?

```
linkBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  contentEl.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div>
      <h3>${title}</h3>
    </div>
    ...etc
  </div>`
})
```

or is there less horrible solution?

Comment: you should look at some sort of backend code like php

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without knowing if/which framework your are using, if you've got a backend, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely up to you. Compare the stackoverflow website with the gmail one. Stackoverflow reloads the whole website as you navigate between pages. This means that your browser is requesting a new resource and the stackoverflow servers are returning that resource, possibly creating it dynamically with new question etc., but then just sending you raw HTML.

On the other hand, gmail loads once, but then fetches each different page entirely through javascript. This could involve asking the gmail server for new messages, but could also be just reworking the HTML to show a settings page, for instance.

There are obviously advantages and disadvantages to both ways of doing things.

---

As a side note, in javascript it is not a great idea to assign to `innerHTML` as this requires that the browser does a lot of work to re-parse the new markdown. Instead you should fully use the DOM model with functions such as `document.createElement` and `Element.appendChild`.

Answer (score 1):

You need not create different pages for each product. Rather use HTML as template.
You can use something like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to make templates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create one UI and fill it with data from some REST API. Look into creating dynamic websites, it is basic stuff.